# Use returned values by a function in an other file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi everybody (excuse my english I'm french)
So my problem is that I have a function it return a values and I need to use this values as parameters for another function in another files 
to illustrate :

```
    def hello():
      cake = int(input('Give a number')
      return cake
```

In my other file there is a function :

```
    if cake != men : ...
```

but cake is not found 
How to do this please (I already import my file1 in the second file)

Comment: That is not a function. That's an `if` statement.

Comment: I know if isn't a function that's just an extraxt of my function

Comment: You should call your function or use `global cake` in your function. Then you can use `cake`

Comment: @howaboutNO how about no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call the function `hello()` which returns the value of `cake`. Note that `cake` is a variable local to the `hello()` function and can not be accessed outside of that function. Assuming that your hello function is defined in a file named `whatever.py`:

```
from whatever import hello

cake = hello()
if cake == men:
    ....
```

or just call the function in the if statement:

```
from whatever import hello

if hello() == men:
    ....
```